# Ionic-v1: Splash screen image is not centered on IPhone Xs Max

Tags: splash-screen, ionic-v1, iphone-xs-max

I have a problem with my Ionic-V1 mobile application on IPhone xs Max (IOS 12).
The splash screen image is not centered.
I was able to fix the IPhone x by adding the required images (1125x2436) to the launchImage resource file in xcode.
I did the same for IPhone Xs Max by adding the required images (1242x2688) to the resource file but it didn't work. The Image still not centered.

Any help will be appcreciated.
Thank you in advance